# How to get the most recent values for each name in a MySql select/join query?

Tags: mysql

I have an SQL query that generates a list of records:

```
SELECT users.uid, users.name, times.entrytype, times.transactionid FROM users 
JOIN cards ON cards.eid = users.uid
JOIN times ON cards.cardid = times.cardid
WHERE users.active = true
AND cards.active = true
AND times.date = "2018-10-25"
ORDER BY users.name ASC, times.transactionid DESC
```

This gives, as an example:

```
1   Joe Bloggs  false   9
1   Joe Bloggs  true    8
1   Joe Bloggs  false   7
1   Joe Bloggs  true    6
1   Joe Bloggs  false   5
1   Joe Bloggs  true    4
3   John Doe    true    10
2   Mary Jane   true    3
2   Mary Jane   false   2
2   Mary Jane   true    1
```

I'm trying to find a way to filter this list down so that I only get the latest (biggest times.transactionid value) entry for each person. The important value is the most recent times.entrytype for each name.

I'd want the result to be:

```
1   Joe Bloggs  false   9
3   John Doe    true    10
2   Mary Jane   true    3
```

I tried grouping on name but that doesn't return the latest times.entrytype (might be earliest?)

I'm aware of PostgreSQL's DISTINCT ON but this is MySQL.

I'm also aware that this appears to be a common sql query pattern, but I can't quite understand exactly how it should work by looking at other examples :/

EDIT:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    uid int,
    name varchar(32),
    active Boolean
);
CREATE TABLE cards (
    eid int,
    cardid int,
    active Boolean
);
CREATE TABLE times (
    cardid int,
    date varchar(16),
    transactionid int,
    entrytype Boolean
);
INSERT INTO users (uid, name, active) VALUES 
( 1, "Joe Bloggs", 1),
( 2, "Mary Jane", 1),
( 3, "John Doe", 1),
( 4, "Bod Dylan", 0);

INSERT INTO cards (eid, cardid, active) VALUES 
( 1, 10, 1),
( 2, 11, 1),
( 3, 12, 1),
( 4, 13, 0);

INSERT INTO times (cardid, date, transactionid, entrytype) VALUES 
( 11, "2018-10-25", 1, 1),
( 11, "2018-10-25", 2, 0),
( 11, "2018-10-25", 3, 1),
( 10, "2018-10-25", 4, 1),
( 10, "2018-10-25", 5, 0),
( 10, "2018-10-25", 6, 1),
( 10, "2018-10-25", 7, 0),
( 10, "2018-10-25", 8, 1),
( 10, "2018-10-25", 9, 0),
( 12, "2018-10-25", 10, 1);
```

SQL Fiddle Link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6b0f0be/1/0

Comment: What is your MySQL server version ? It can be solved using Window function on 8.0.2 and above

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: What column from your result set represents `times.trans`  value ?

Comment: SQL Fiddle link added

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Sorry, I meant the times.transactionid value. Edited to clarify this (column 3 in the results)

Comment: `cards.eid = users.uid` Bear in mind that some day you're going to forget what an eid is.

Comment: @Dave What is your MySQL server version ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya  Select Version(); returns 10.1.13-MariaDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html) determine the maximum value of `transactionid` for a specific `uid`. You can also shift your `Where` conditions to this Sub-select query.
- Now, Join this result-set back to the main tables.
- For MySQL version 8.0.2 and onwards, it can be approached in a "more-efficient" manner using [Window Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html) with [`Row_Number()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number).

Try the following query:

```
SELECT users.uid, 
       users.name, 
       times.entrytype, 
       times.transactionid 
FROM 
  (SELECT u1.uid, 
          MAX(t1.transactionid) AS max_transactionid 
   FROM users AS u1 
   JOIN cards AS c1 ON c1.eid = u1.uid 
   JOIN times AS t1 ON t1.cardid = c1.cardid 
   WHERE u1.active = true AND 
         c1.active = true AND 
         t1.date = '2018-10-25'
   GROUP BY u1.uid
  ) AS dt
JOIN users ON users.uid = dt.uid 
JOIN times ON times.transactionid = dt.max_transactionid
ORDER BY users.name ASC, 
         times.transactionid DESC
```

**Result:**

```
| uid | name       | entrytype | transactionid |
| --- | ---------- | --------- | ------------- |
| 1   | Joe Bloggs | 0         | 9             |
| 3   | John Doe   | 1         | 10            |
| 2   | Mary Jane  | 1         | 3             |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mdhUdtVwfxtKhbnKF2apmx/1)